# Retrieving a video frame in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get the video frame of a .mp4 file:

```
String fontPath = "test.mp4";
Bitmap b = getVideoFrame(fontPath);
```

And my function:

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(String FD) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(FD);
        return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I get the error`IllegalArgumentException` on that line:

```
retriever.setDataSource(FD);
```

`test.mp4` is in an assets directory in my project.

Comment: [Are you sure your file path is valid?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String))

Comment: No but I don't know how to be sure. I try different ways to get the path but each time I get this error